# Big gap below A4 div when printing to A4 PDF with html-pdf-chrome

Tags: php, html, css, reactjs, pdf

I am currently using the `westy92 / html-pdf-chrome` library for printing HTML to PDF in my Laravel project. My front-end is based on React.

I have created a set of divs to function as A4 pages:

```
<div id="pdf" className="printable-pdf">
    <div className="editor">
        <div className="editor__page"
            style={{
                padding: '20mm',
                background: '#eb4034',
            }}>
            <p>First page</p>
        </div>
        <div className="editor__page"
            style={{
                padding: '20mm',
                background: '#1e7985'
            }}>
        <p>Second page</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
}

.printable-pdf {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.editor {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;

  &__page {
    background: white;
    width: 8.3in;
    height: 11.7in;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 1.25cm solid #000;
  }
}

@page {
  size: A4;
  margin: 0;
}

@media print {
  body,
  .editor__page {
    margin: 0;
    border: initial;
    border-radius: initial;
    width: initial;
    min-height: initial;
    box-shadow: initial;
    background: initial;
    page-break-after: always;
  }
}
```

It use emogrify to style my css inline when printing and an example of the output is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;">
<head style="-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" style="-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;">
<style type="text/css">@media print {body,.editor__page{margin: 0;
    border: initial;
    border-radius: initial;
    width: initial;
    min-height: initial;
    box-shadow: initial;
    background: initial;
    page-break-after: always;}}</style>
</head>
<body style="-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;"><div class="editor" style="-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
<div class="editor__page" style="-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; width: 8.3in; height: 11.7in; display: block; margin: 0 auto; box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); border: 1.25cm solid #000; padding: 20mm; background: rgb(235, 64, 52);"><p style="-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;">First page</p></div>
<div class="editor__page" style="-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; width: 8.3in; height: 11.7in; display: block; margin: 0 auto; box-shadow: 0 0 0.5cm rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); border: 1.25cm solid #000; padding: 20mm; background: rgb(30, 121, 133);"><p style="-webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;">Second page</p></div>
</div></body>
</html>
```

To visualize what I am expecting, this is my HTML div vs what is printed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2N2FV.jpg

As you can see I get bit gaps at the bottom of the pages. I have already checked the size through Adobe, and both div and PDF output are in A4 format.

At last, these are my html-pdf-chrome settings, setup with docker:

```
const htmlPdf = require('html-pdf-chrome');
const http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    let html = '';
    request.on('data', function (chunk) {
        return html += chunk;
    });
    request.on('end', async function () {
        response.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/pdf'
        });

        let pdf = await htmlPdf.create(html, {
            port: 9222,
            printOptions: {
                printBackground: true,
                paperWidth: 8.3,
                paperHeight: 11.7,
                marginTop: 0,
                marginBottom: 0,
                marginRight: 0,
                marginLeft: 0,
                scale: 1,
                footerTemplate: '',
                displayHeaderFooter: false,
            }
        });
        let buffer = pdf.toBuffer();

        response.end(buffer);
    });

}).listen(8765);
```

To clarify my goal, I'm trying to make pages which print 1:1 between html and PDF, but have the issue of whitespace in the bottom of my pages on print. How do I make my div fit properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out this was caused by box-sizing and fixed it by adding:

```
* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
```

Maybe someone can explain further why this is the cause, as I simply got to this result by trial/error.